# Expedia: migrate to TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

During years, I've been hitting Expedia API following this instructions:

https://developers.expediagroup.com/docs/rapid/resources/reference/signature-authentication

I got an email saying that I need to change old ciphers, and instead use one from this list:

```
TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-HACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
```

They don't offer too much explanation. I'm lost, because e.g. if I want to use TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384 then I need to use a key which is 32 bytes length, but the api key and secret keys that Expedia sent to me some years ago are 26 bytes length.

I'm using Go 1.12, maybe that is the problem? Maybe the underlying http/net package is old and accepts old ciphers and I need to use a new version of Go?

Comment: *"if I want to use TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384 then I need to use a key which is 32 bytes length, but the api key and secret keys that Expedia sent to me some years ago are 26 bytes length."* - The key used to authenticate against the API is unrelated to the key used for encryption within TLS. It is more likely that you are using an ancient version of Go with no support for TLS 1.3 - this was enabled by default in 1.13 (2019).

Comment: I figured this out last night. You are right. I really thought they were asking me to cipher the requests using the key pair that I was granted with. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: the cause of the issue is that I'm using Go 1.12, which doesn't have the expected list of ciphers by Expedia. Upgrading to at least 1.13 will fix it.